# SncRedisBundle (predis) - heroku : how to configure the DSN

Tags: php, symfony, heroku, redis, predis

I'm using SncRedisBundle with success locally but can't have it work using heroku.
Here is my config :

```
#config.yml

imports:
    - { resource: heroku/parameters_heroku.php } #heroku cloud provider configuration's

snc_redis:
    clients:
        default:
            type: predis
            alias: default
            dsn: "%redis_url%"
        cache:
            type: predis
            alias: cache
            dsn: "%redis_url%&database=1"
            logging: false
        session:
            type: predis
            alias: session
            dsn: "%redis_url%&database=2"
        task:
            type: predis
            alias: task
            dsn: "%redis_url%&database=3"
        doctrine:
            type: predis
            alias: doctrine
            dsn: "%redis_url%&database=4"
    session:
        client: session
        ttl: 10800 #le session expirera apres 3 heures
    doctrine:
        metadata_cache:
            client: doctrine
            entity_manager: default          # the name of your entity_manager connection
            document_manager: default        # the name of your document_manager connection
        result_cache:
            client: doctrine
            entity_manager: [default]  # you may specify multiple entity_managers
        query_cache:
            client: doctrine
            entity_manager: default
        second_level_cache:
            client: doctrine
            entity_manager: default
    monolog:
        client: cache
        key: monolog
    swiftmailer:
        client: default
        key: swiftmailer
```

---

```
#heroku/parameters_heroku.php
<?php
$is_heroku = getenv("IS_HEROKU");//manually added :  heroku config:set IS_HEROKU=1


if (!$is_heroku) {
    return;
}

if ($redisUrl = getenv('REDIS_URL')) {
    $aParsedRedisUrl = parse_url($redisUrl);
    $redisConstructedDsn = 'redis://'.$aParsedRedisUrl['host'].':'.$aParsedRedisUrl['port'].$aParsedRedisUrl['path'].'?'.'password='.$aParsedRedisUrl['pass'].($aParsedRedisUrl['query'] ? '&'.$aParsedRedisUrl['query'] : ''); // le user ne sert pas : .'&user='.$aParsedRedisUrl['user']
    $container->setParameter('redis_url', $redisConstructedDsn);
}
```

---

if I dump `$redisConstructedDsn` during the heroku build process, I've got something like that : `redis://xxxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:18839?password=foobar`, so, it seem pretty compatible with [predis doc](https://github.com/nrk/predis/wiki/Connection-Parameters) 
but the composer construction fails with a

> remote:          [Predis\Response\ServerException]   remote:
>   NOAUTH Authentication required.

I can't find what I did wrong

Answer (score 0):

problem solved : 
initially I used this kind of syntax : `dsn: "%redis_url%/3"` wich is incompatible with heroku.
When I changed it to an acceptable format : `"%redis_url%?database=3"`, I added bug elsewhere, so here is the simple correction in `heroku/parameters_heroku.php`

```
if ($redisUrl = getenv('REDIS_URL')) {
    $container->setParameter('redis_url', $redisUrl);
}
```

some resources on the internet will say that predis isn't compatible with heroku's format, but they are old&wrong ;)